# Cannot reach the text consoles at tty2, tty3, tty4

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, kde, tty

Yesterday I updated my Ubuntu 21.10, but after rebooting I cannot switch to the text consoles tty2, tty3, tty4, although I have been using them for more than 10 years.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd> is now ignored, at the login screen and also under KDE.

`ps` shows that the consoles are running:

```
F   UID     PID    PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND

4     0    2047       1  20   0   3156  1100 -      Ss+  ttyS1      0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --keep-baud 115200,57600,38400,9600 ttyS1 vt220
4     0    2078    2060  20   0 1443172 266312 -    Ssl+ tty1      58:22 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{5a868172-394c-4080-8710-61a3d82d9962} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
4     0    7217       1  20   0   3168  1092 -      Ss+  tty2       0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty2 linux
4     0   12702       1  20   0   3168  1128 -      Ss+  tty3       0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty3 linux
4     0  102500       1  20   0   3168  1124 -      Ss+  tty4       0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty4 linux
```

But the usual switching to a console does not work, e. g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. The keys are working, e. g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> for termination, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> for closing a window or program.

I am using this configuration:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.2
- Kernel Version: 5.13.0-22-lowlatency (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
- Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530

How can I enable switching to the text consoles again?

Comment: Why are you running with 5.13.0-22-lowlatency? I you boot to a Kubuntu Live USB, do the keys work then?

Comment: If you log into a different user account, do the keys work?

Comment: I have used the text consoles since 5 years, without a problem. And using another keyboard did changed nothing. So the bug is in the software, not in the hardware. I am using the lowlatency kernel more then 5 years, and no other kernels on my PC.

Comment: You didn't answer the two most important questions... booting to a Kubuntu Live USB... and trying a different user account...

Comment: I have done an update, reboot and now it works.

Comment: What kind of update? Software Updater? Write down the details as an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I made the update with a few lines:                                                                                                      apt-get update  
aptitude update  
apt-get update --fix-missing  
apt-get upgrade  
aptitude upgrade  
apt-get -u dselect-upgrade  
aptitude -f install  
apt-get -f install  
aptitude --full-resolver install  
aptitude install  
aptitude clean  
aptitude autoclean  
aptitude safe-upgrade